# setBackGroundColor resets the shape of view

Tags: android, xml, view, shapes

I want to have circular `TextView`s and I'm doing this by defining a shape drawable that works fine.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >
    <solid android:color="@color/White"/>
</shape>
```

I want different colors of this `TextView`, so I do this in my code:

```
setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red));
```

But **it resets the TextView shape to rectangle!**

So, the question summarizes to **What's the correct way to dynamically change only the color of a view?**

Comment: Is R.color.Red your custom xml?

Comment: @MysticMagic: no, it's a simple color value

Answer (score 1):

It becomes a rectangle because you are changing the background of the view which of course is rectangle shaped, you should change the solid color but i don't think this possible to do programmatically

the only way is to do like this:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval" >
    <solid android:color="@color/Red"/>
</shape>
```

and:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval" >
    <solid android:color="@color/green"/>
</shape>
```

then:

```
setBackgroundResource(R.color.green);
```

Comment: I came with that myself but in case there is many colors you must create 20 xml files. It's against the DRY principle!

Answer (score 1):

You can change background of shape of a view by programmatically by doing like this:

```
GradientDrawable drawable = (GradientDrawable)textView.getBackground();
    drawable.setColor(getResources().getColor(android.R.color.darker_gray));
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use**

```
setBackground(drawable);
```

**Instead of**

```
setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.Red));
```